# SVG .end event not working?

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to learn and play with some basic SVG animations. I was going through a [tutorial/guide on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/), and noticed that the `.end` event doesn't work in Chrome and Safari. What gives? Is this not supported or a bug?? Seems silly for a simple thing like. Or maybe it's a bug with Codepen?

Example Codepen - http://codepen.io/jaminroe/pen/xGQvEE/?editors=110

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use - in an id if you're going to use it with animate as it's assumed that you're starting a time offset such as id-5s

You can do if you really must but you have to escape them i.e.

```
begin="circ\-anim.end"
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know this yet, but apparently you can't use hyphens in the ID of an SVG `<animate>` element. *facepalm*

I changed my ID from `circ-anim` to `circAnim`.

Comment: You can use hyphens if you want, it's just simplest not to.