# SVG animation not properly working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, svg-animate

I am new in SVG animation, I am working on SVG polygon animation, it is working fine in Chrome and FireFox but have some trouble in Safari (MAC)
on Safari first time it is working fine but second time it is just showing close the box, not showing to open. 
The scenario is when click on red button, it open the box and after setTimeOut() 900, the close function(document.getElementById('animation-to-close').beginElement()) is run to close the box..

```js
resizePage();
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('animation-to-click').beginElement();

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('animation-to-close').beginElement();
  }, 900);

});

function resizePage() {

  var pageHeight = $(window).height() - 100;
  var circleTopPosition = pageHeight / 2;
  $("#circle").css("top", circleTopPosition - 216);
  setContentBox("#0d915d");

}

function setContentBox() {
  var getScreenWidth = $(window).width() - 165;
  var getScreenHeight = $(window).height() - 100;
  var getScreenHeightEachPart = $(window).width() * 2;
  // create svg:
  var svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]; //Get svg element
  
  $("#cover").css("width", getScreenWidth);
  $("#cover").css("height", getScreenHeight);
  var polygonElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'polygon'); //Create a path in SVG's namespace
  polygonElement.setAttribute("points", "0," + getScreenHeight / 2 + " 820," + getScreenHeight / 2 + " 820," + getScreenHeight / 2);
  // polygonElement.setAttribute("style", "fill:#0d915d");


  // create open animation
  var animateElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'animate'); //Create a path in SVG's namespace
  animateElement.setAttribute("id", "animation-to-click");
  animateElement.setAttribute("begin", "shape.click");
  animateElement.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  animateElement.setAttribute("attributeName", "points");
  animateElement.setAttribute("dur", "550ms");
  // animateElement.setAttribute("class", "boxGg");

  animateElement.setAttribute("to", "0," + getScreenHeight / 2 + " " + getScreenWidth + "," + getScreenHeightEachPart + " " + getScreenWidth + ",-" + getScreenHeightEachPart);

  // create close animation
  var closeBoxElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'animate'); //Create a path in SVG's namespace
  closeBoxElement.setAttribute("id", "animation-to-close");
  closeBoxElement.setAttribute("begin", "shape.click");
  closeBoxElement.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
  closeBoxElement.setAttribute("attributeName", "points");
  closeBoxElement.setAttribute("dur", "550ms");
  closeBoxElement.setAttribute("to", "0," + getScreenHeight / 2 + " 820," + getScreenHeight / 2 + " 820," + getScreenHeight / 2);


  // append animate tag into 
  polygonElement.appendChild(animateElement);

  polygonElement.appendChild(closeBoxElement);

  svg.appendChild(polygonElement);
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background: Red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">
  Click Me
</div>
<svg id="cover"></svg>
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue and it turned out the "problem" was IDs that contained hyphens (see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732492/)). Try changing all instances of `animation-to-click` and `animation-to-close` to `animationToClick` and `animationToClose` and seeing if that doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg, I did same thing remove hyphens from all IDs but no luck, have still same issue :(

Comment: A bit late, but for anyone searching, Safari has a bug and requires resetting via `svg.pauseAnimations(); svg.setCurrentTime(0); svg.unpauseAnimations();` before repeat animations with `beginElement`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234572/strange-safari-behavior-with-multiple-svg-animates)